# Second order non-linear PDE to ODE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

In Evans's book on PDE, in page 98 there is  list of ODEs that are derived from every PDE of first order. Is there any similar method for second order PDE?

Comment: As far as I  know, no. There would be far too few equations to solve for many variables (even double derivative etc classify as variables, then you are unable to generate so many equations).

Comment: Why linear? in Evans you don't get linear ODE's from the PDE. I don't want linear ODE. I just need the ODE for some other end.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added the word linear by mistake.